# Splash Screen With App Icon effect IOS7

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, xcode5

My app has an App Icon and Default@2x.png for retina display. When My App launches, my Icon is stretched out with the Splash Screen which can have a weird effect. Can anyone show me how I can avoid this?

Answer (score 2):

Please Read the below icon sizes and cross check with your icon.

For the best results, enlist the help of a **professional graphic designer**. An experienced graphic designer can help you develop an overall visual style for your app and apply that style to all the icons and images in it.

Create different sizes of the app icon for different devices. If you’re creating a universal app, you need to supply app icons in all four sizes.

For **iPhone and iPod touch**, both of these sizes are required:

```
120 x 120 pixels
60 x 60 pixels (standard resolution)
```

For **iPad**, both of these sizes are required:

```
152 x 152
76 x 76 pixels (standard resolution)
```

When iOS displays an app icon on the Home screen of a device, it automatically applies a mask that rounds the corners. Make sure your icon has 90° corners so it looks good after the mask is applied.

For more : [developer.apple - userexperience- AppIcons](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/AppIcons.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH19-SW1)

Answer (score 1):

You can't adjust the app loading animation at all (the icon zoom on iOS7), but you can adjust your default screenshot image to flow better with your icon, or better yet, don't include a splash screen at all but rather a minimized UI as recommended by Apple.